# Cant read char * from c function, using VB

Tags: c, vb.net, vb6, char

Having a problem reading a `char *` from a dll function written in C.

DLL is called rapdll.dll. its header file looks like:

```
extern "C"{void _stdcall New_Rapdll(void);}  
extern "C"{void _stdcall TCP_Set_RelayIO(char *Ipaddress,char *SerialNumber,char *Password,char *Data);}  
extern "C"{Variant _stdcall Get_Receivedata(void);}
```

I dont have source code for the DLL. The help file for the command I am having problems with (Get_Receivedata()) is:

Declaration

```
Char * Get_Receivedata(void)
```

Example:

```
Get_Receivedata ()
```

Return Value:

```
See Response from RAP: Success  
Data empty: Fail  
Description:  
This function is getting response from RAP.
```

Code I have written so far is:

```
Public Class Form1  
Declare Sub TCP_Set_RelayIO Lib "rapdll.dll" (ByVal Ipaddress As String, ByVal Serial As String, ByVal Pass As String, ByVal Relay As String)  
Declare Sub TCP_Get_SerialNumber Lib "rapdll.dll" (ByVal Ipaddress As String, ByVal Pass As String)  
Declare Sub New_Rapdll Lib "rapdll.dll" ()  
Declare Function Get_Receivedata Lib "rapdll.dll" () As String  
Dim Result As String  


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub

Function rap() As String
    Result = Get_Receivedata()
    Return Result
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim st As String
    Call New_Rapdll()
    Call TCP_Set_RelayIO("192.168.1.2", "0000", "0000", "00120")
    st = rap()
    MsgBox(st)

    End
End Sub
End Class
```

Everything works fine up to the **st = rap()** line. The command before it "Call TCP_Set_RelayIO("192.168.1.2", "0000", "0000", "00120")" works properly, as it does reset the relay in this device. But when I try to read the reply using the `Get_Receivedata` function, i get An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'.

I know the problem is trying to read the `char *` return from the `Get_Receivedata` function, but I am not sure how to do this properly.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: From my experiments, returning `char*` isn't an issue.  Can you please confirm the return value of `Get_Receivedata()`.  If it indeed returns a Variant, you may want to try making it indeed return a Variant (which I am not sure would even work).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look right (`Variant`):

```
extern "C"{Variant _stdcall Get_Receivedata(void);}
```

Anyway, I really recommend that you use a parameter instead.  Something like this...

C++:

```
extern "C"{void _stdcall Get_Receivedata(char** data);}
```

VB:

```
Declare Function Get_Receivedata Lib "rapdll.dll" (ByRef Data As String)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont have access to the source code. i wish I did, it would make things much easier. So, I am stuck with trying to get this to work with the existing DLL. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the return from `Get_Receivedata()` from `String` to `Object` or `Variant` (as well as your Result variable).  You could also try a `Byte` array.  If it stops the crash, you may just need to figure out the byte breakdown of the return and maybe make a `Type` or do some `CopyMemory()` trickery.

Comment: Tried changing to Object and now I get: PInvoke restriction: cannot return variants. Changing to Byte() gets me: Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination.

Comment: I just realized (by your error code) that this was not VB6.  I was browsing VB6 topics when I came across this and if you don't notice the Public Class and Handles code, it still looks like VB6.  I'm not sure if it is possible to Marshal a `Variant` return from C++, but you could try variations of this- `Declare Function Get_Receivedata Lib "rapdll.dll" () As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)> Object` (AsAny is just a guess). Only other option I can think of would be to write a wrapper that returns more friendly types.  Good Luck!

Comment: Thats funny, as i just tried that last night. Using VB6 and changing the declare and dim from string to variant, it works with no errors. but anything newer than VB6, gives the unable to return variant error. I will try your suggestion. Thank You!

Comment: I have tried every possible combination of marshaling I can think of. i definitely think marshaling is the way to go, but just not sure of what the combination would be as far as declaring and what the result variable should be. Any ideas?

Comment: That's why I said it may not be possible.  When I was looking for the answer, I came across this page http://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/c-interop-how-to-return-a-variant-from-an-unmanaged-function/.  Notice point #5 about not being able to return a variant.  I hate to say this, but your best bet might be to make a wrapper in another language (C++ wrapper to return the right type, or a simpler one).  Looks like VB6 would be an option too... .NET -> VB6 -> C++ -> VB6 -> .NET.  If you know C++, that'd be the better route I'd say.